# How to automatically update a field based on user input?

Tags: list, document-library

I have a document library in which different organizations need to review and provide comments based on the following steps:

1. Document is added with a list of required reviewers and a list of remaining reviewers
2. Required reviewer looks at document and either concurs or provides open comment via a form
3. Document creator manually updates list of remaining reviewers by removing those who have provided comments

Is there a way to automate step 3?

[image]

Comment: Are you using SPO or On-Prem? You can add multilevel approval workflow (either MS Flow or SPD Workflow) step so it all goes to automation.

Comment: I am using SPO, but we cannot use Workflow with our current customer. Is there a way to add JavaScript for it?

Comment: So let me understand the scenario, you have multiple reviews for document in no particular sequence. Each reviewer can come and either approve the document or add some comments to update the document. Once the created update the document, it goes back to reviewer to view and approve it. Once all the reviewer approve the document, it publish the document.